# Using the % command in c++

Tags: cursor-movement, filetype-c++

The `%` command is quite nice, and I use it to copy/delete whole loops, functions and classes.

In c++ though, you need to add a `;` after your class declaration, so trying to motion over a whole class won't work with the `%` command.

Is there a way to get the command to carry on the motion? I guess just adding a `f;` will be enough, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 5):

You can force a motion to be linewise; then, the `%` would include the full last line, including the trailing `;`, for example `yV%`. Unfortunately, if you use the *matchit* plugin, that doesn't work any more, but you can instead use visual mode: `V%y` (interestingly, this is the reverse of the above!)

Alternatively, you could define a custom motion for that.